# Tabulator row formatting removes hover effect, while cell formatting doesn't

Tags: javascript, css, tabulator

My goal is to set the background color of the row based on the cell value.

The coloring works for both, but the row one loses the hover effect.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-cookies-wxy8d?file=/src/index.js)

Is there a way to have the row coloring behave as the cell one?

The reason for this is to keep the alternating row color, while having the background over it, without losing hover.

Here's the code here as well...

```js
let data = [
  { string: "aaaaaaaaaa", number: 0 },
  { string: "bbbbbbbbbb", number: 0 },
  { string: "cccccccccc", number: 1 },
  { string: "dddddddddd", number: 1 },
  { string: "eeeeeeeeee", number: 0 },
  { string: "ffffffffff", number: 1 },
  { string: "gggggggggg", number: 0 },
  { string: "hhhhhhhhhh", number: 0 }
];

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  data: data,
  rowFormatter: row => {

    let data = row.getData();

    if (data.number === 1) {
      row.getElement().style.cssText += "background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);";
    }
  },
  columns: [
    {
      title: "string",
      field: "string"
    },
    {
      title: "number",
      field: "number",
      formatter: cell => {
        if (cell.getValue() === 0) {
          cell.getElement().style.cssText += "background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);";
        }
        return cell.getValue();
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: When using .style.cssText, it replaces all css on the element. To only replace the background-color, do .style.backgroundColor=red. Let me know if that doesn’t fix the problem.

Comment: Damn, I made a mistake in the code. I actually use `style.cssText += "background...", but it still doesn't work. Why does it work for the cell, and not the row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover color is applied using the css `:hover` and setting the `backgroundColor`.  So when you apply `backgroundColor` inline, you are overriding the color that is applied from the css file.

You can take the css and apply it in your app css, with `!important`, so that it is applied even in the case of inline styling.

You can also maintain it with JavaScript event listeners on mouseout/in.  This would probably not be easy to maintain with the virtual dom.  I do not recommend attempting this.

To override the css, I believe this is what you need.

```
.tabulator-row.tabulator-selectable:hover {
  background-color: #bbb !important;
}
```

Here is your example modified.
https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-cache-xpyy9?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Hmmmm, not quite, but gave me the right idea. I'll accept the answer. Here's the working example of exactly what I wanted. https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-williams-no5us?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Can you help me out a bit? I can't figure out the selector for this case, when the table has frozen columns, it doesn't work for them. https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-williams-no5us?file=/src/index.js

Comment: It looks like the background-color for the frozen cell is set to inherit.  It should take the parent color, but I honestly don't know that much about css.  Maybe it inherits the parent color, but not the parents :hover color?  Not really sure.  In any case, the class selector is .tabulator-cell.tabulator-frozen:hover for the hover event on the frozen cells.  https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-morning-emuu0?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: It looks like it does take the parent color and not the parent's :hover color.  If you want it to use the parent's :hover color, then do background-image: inherit on the .tabulator-cell.tabulator-frozen:hover selector.